# Accessing a method on a generic base class

Tags: c#

I have multiple classes inheriting from a generic base class. I would like to have an arbitrary collection of instances of these child classes, and on any given child, to be able to call a method from the generic base class.

```
public class Pair<A, B>
{
    protected readonly A value1;
    protected readonly B value2;

    public Pair(A value1, B value2)
    {
        this.value1 = value1;
        this.value2 = value2;
    }

    public string ValueOneString()
    {
        return value1.ToString();
    }
}

public class AuPair : Pair<string, int>
{
    public AuPair(string key, int value) : base(key, value) { }
}

public class RePair : Pair<bool, double>
{
    public RePair(bool key, double value) : base(key, value) { }
}

public class Program
{
    public static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        var pair = new Pair<int, int>(76, 4);
        var auPair = new AuPair("Mart", 25);
        var rePair = new RePair(false, 2.371);

        var pairs = new List<dynamic> { pair, auPair, rePair };

        Console.WriteLine(pairs[0].ValueOneString());
        Console.WriteLine(pairs[1].ValueOneString());
        Console.WriteLine(pairs[2].ValueOneString());

        return 0;
    }
}
```

Is there a concrete collection I can store these pairs in that isn't a `List<dynamic>` ? I thought it would look like `List<Pair<,>>` or `List<Pair>`, but neither are correct and I cannot find a proper collection to use. I would like to call the GetKeyString() method on a concrete class rather than gamble with the dynamic keyword.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an abstract base class that isn't generic and make sure the methods are defined on it:

```
public abstract class BasePair
{
    public abstract string ValueOneString();
}
```

then the generic can derive from it:

```
public class Pair<A, B> : BasePair
{
    ...

    public override string ValueOneString()
    {
        return value1.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then your collection can use `BasePair` for the generic parameter:

```
var pairs = new List<BasePair>();
```

Edit: If the base is entirely abstract, there's no reason it couldn't be an interface instead.